# Azure Keyvault Local Issues

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I've been using Keyvault for a while with Managed Identity. But for this project I'm getting weird results when developing locally.

For some reason, if I do not have ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true, when developing on my local machine, it throws an error and will not get a secret. If I add that flag, it uses my visual studio credentials like it is supposed to.

Very confused why I would have to add that flag as I never have before.

```
    using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();

    DefaultAzureCredentialOptions options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
    {
        Diagnostics =
            {
                LoggedHeaderNames = { "x-ms-request-id" },
                LoggedQueryParameters = { "api-version" },
                IsLoggingContentEnabled = true,
                IsAccountIdentifierLoggingEnabled = true,

            },
            ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true
    };
    var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(xxx), new DefaultAzureCredential(options));
```

Error:

Not sure why it is even trying managed identity locally, and why it doesn't fail and continue to use visual studio identity.

[image]

Summary: Works fine in cloud, and works fine local when adding ExcludeManagedidentityCredential = true. Not sure why I need that flag locally.

Comment: Setting to true disables authenticating with managed identity endpoints.

Comment: Please refer [DefaultAzureIdentity](https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/08/azure-identity-201/) for more information

Comment: Yes, but why is it trying that locally, and why is it failing there before successfully using visual studio authentication. Ive never had to do this.bit should short circuit after getting VS creds, which do work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/28218

Try downgrading Azure.Identity to 1.4 (if possible) to see if the problem continues to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks... worked at 1.4. Just another bug by MS it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a Key Vault access policy for the user logged in Visual Studio. Please see: [Assign a Key Vault access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal), but on the step with "Select principal*" select the user instead of an app managed identity

Comment: That isn't it either. It works as it should as long as I put that property to true

Answer (score 0):

Did you always set this to true?

> IsAccountIdentifierLoggingEnabled = true

Set the above to false and see if it works locally without need for setting ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential to true.

Comment: Yes, if I do not explicitly set that to true, it no longer works..